# Using a temporary object without storing it in variable

Tags: c++, temporary

Let's take an example where we need to insert the vector returned from a function to another vector:

```cpp
const std::vector<int> getvec(){
    return {1, 2, 3};
}

// in main...
std::vector<int> foo{ 11, 12 };
auto bar = getvec();
foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
```

The fact that the `bar` variable needs to be referenced twice in the `insert()` method makes it necessary to have the vector stored as a variable (we could otherwise do `foo.myinsert(getvec())` should there be such an interface).

It is a bit annoying to me that in such a case, we need to introduce a variable `foo` in the main scope which is not meant to be used again in the rest of the code, as it occupies the memory and also pollutes the namespace. Especially a problem if we are talking about with a large "temporary" object.

Is there a standard approach to deal with that? We could define a function that take the "temporary" object only once so that we can directly feed function output to it, but would be difficult to manage if we need to define such function for every similar scenario. Also as in this example we are not able to define a member function for `vector` class.

Alternatively what using braces to limit the scope of the "temporary" part of the insertion but I would like to know if any caveat here.

```cpp
vector<int> foo{ 11, 12 };
{ // extra brace here
    auto bar = getvec();
    foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
} // extra brace here
```

Comment: You've sort of inflicted the problem on yourself, by writing a function that returns a vector by value - which means the vector needs to exist somewhere in order to pass it (or iterators from it in your case) to another function which then iterates over its elements - in this case the call of `foo.insert()`.   You would need to eliminate the function - for example, `foo.insert(foo.end(), {1,2,3})`

Comment: If you're really wanting something generic, have a look at a naive attempt using templates: https://ideone.com/q1qRIw ..  Of course, this isn't actually as performant as creating a function that operates directly on vectors, or storing the return value in a temporary.  It's also more abstract and less intuitive to work with.  The more you try to make clean, general purpose functions to avoid common idioms, the more you'll just end up in the weeds.

Comment: Honestly, your scoping example at the end of your OP is totally fine if this is really your use case. Anything beyond that is over-complicating unnecessarily.

Comment: "as it occupies the memory and also pollutes the namespace. " Two curlys around and the namespace "problem" is gone. And memory is not used more or less with a named or a unnamed object. The compiler will optimize out all and everything. If you really believe that an additional template/function/lambda is useful as proposed by the answers, you can do it. They will also be optimized out I believe, but is that a real problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but you could use a temporary lambda instead of a separate function, and declaring and invoking it in the same statement avoids the need for braces to limit its scope.

```
const std::vector<int> getvec(){
    return {1, 2, 3};
}

// in main...
std::vector<int> foo{ 11, 12 };
[&](const auto &bar){ foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end()); }(getvec());
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/V641oW)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a little template function to do this, which takes a vector by const reference (which can bind to a temporary and extend its lifetime):

```
template<typename C>
void append(std::vector<C> &invec, const std::vector<C> &temp)
{
    invec.insert(std::end(invec), std::begin(temp), std::end(temp));
}
```

and this could be used for all other types of vectors. Then you can call it like this:

```
append(foo, getvec());
```

Working demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YhnE5n).

Answer (score 0):

You can make strings of other things than char. Thru `basic_string<int>` you can access `string::append` ( and other things )

```
using strint = std::basic_string<int>;
strint getVec () {
    return { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
}

strint foo{ 6, 7 };
foo += getVec();
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h4naTa